# $x=3 \cos^3(t),\, y=3 \sin^3(t)$, rearrange for $t$, how to handle ($\cos^3$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

I know arccos is the opposite of cos, in the way multiplication is the opposite of division,

$$ x=3 \cos^3(t),\, y=3 \sin^3(t) $$

but I am unsure how to rearrange the equation in terms of $t$, as I do not know how to handle $\cos^3$.

Comment: $$\cos^3t=\dfrac x3,\cos^2t=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee did you mean $\cos t = ?$?

Comment: i mean how would you get each functions to be the subject of t, not the subject of cos^3(t)

Comment: @KennyLau, I suggested the usage of  $$\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
3\cos^3(t) &=& x\\
\cos^3(t) &=& \dfrac x3\\
\cos(t) &=& \sqrt[3]{\dfrac x3}\\
t &=& \arccos\sqrt[3]{\dfrac x3}\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: well that actually makes a lot of sense, i guess i was looking at cos^3() as its own operator rather than realising it is made up of two different opperators, thank you.